# Best approach for an enterprise Java web application

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am working on building a membership management web application using Java (Servlet / JSP - MVC model), but I am a bit confused on best frameworks to use in order to ensure 1) Stability 2) speed and 3) Performance

In term of database operations, I've read other developers recommending Hibernate, others recommend using JDBC so I am not sure which is best? And is there something better than those 2 to help me maintain performance, speed and stability? Taking in consideration that the application might have huge load of users accessing it in any specific point and will be maintaining a database of more than 150,000+ members.

In term of best framework, I am following the MVC model using Servlet / JSP, but some other developers recommended using Spring MVC so is this the best approach? and if yes can you please explain why based on your experience?

Any other recommendations / suggestions for frameworks, approaches or even Eclipse plugins to help me through the development of this project will be highly appreciated

Thanks for your time

Comment: First, this question is OT (IMHO). Second, if you're going to build a high volume web site without any experience with regards to the frameworks listed above, you should consider hiring the required skills. Third, 'best' is a fairly subjective term...

Comment: ditch eclipse and use intellij, I like the spring stack

Comment: @home IMHO there is nothing wrong in learning from others experience, and if every developer needs to build a high volume website hired another developer to do the job, no new developer will ever learn :) Anyway, thanks for sharing your opinion :)

Comment: @NimChimpsky Thanks a lot for sharing your opinion, can you please tell me more information why you prefer intellij over eclipse? Is it the IDE itself? its plugins? support?

Comment: @MChan: There is a mistake in your argumentation as you're going to learn from those 'external' experts. More important, it's nearly impossible to answer your question just within a forum. You should do some research so that you're in a position to make sound decisions regarding the frameworks - and have your NFR in mind :-)

Comment: @home I've already made some research, including reading a lot of posts/ forums talking about pros and cons. But I am more keen to hear about other developers experience...why do they prefer X technology over Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC is the lowest level of handling the database, it's the fastest but not the easiest way to do it. A lot of boilerplate coding is involved.

Hibernate is much better approach as long as you use best practices and don't add items to lists that can have huge number or items (see [this article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/hibernate-mapped-collections.html)).

There is also MyBatis (formerly iBATIS), see it [in action](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/getting-started.html).

As for the web side if you're using Spring it's probably best to stick to its MVC solution.

If you are working with a experienced web designer a better approach would be [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) - he can do his job of designing HTML/CSS/JS and you can work on the server side without worrying about HTML tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cebence for sharing your experience, I truly appreciate you taking the time to share it with me.